# Reasons Equals() on Tuple could return false

Tags: c#

I have some code where wanted to use Tuples as key for a Dictionary, but I'm having problems getting the keys recognized properly.

```
Dictionary<Tuple<string, MyClass>, MyClass> Map = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, MyClass>, MyClass>
{
  { Tuple.Create(s1, new MyClass { value = v1 }), new MyClass { value = r1 } }
}

Tuple<string, MyClass> key = Tuple.Create(s, o);
foreach (Tuple<string, MyClass> t in Map.Keys)
{
  if (t.GetType() == key.GetType()
    && t.Item1.Equals(key.Item1) && t.Item2.Equals(key.Item2)
    && t.Item1.GetHashCode() == key.Item1.GetHashCode() && t.Item2.GetHashCode() == key.Item2.GetHashCode())
  {
    bool test2 = t.Equals(key); // False?
    bool test3 = t.GetHashCode() == key.GetHashCode(); // True
  }
}
```

- Both t and key are of type System.Tuple< string, domain.MyClass >
- The individual values should be considered equal, as I have implemented the Equals method in MyClass - this is also checked in the if-statement
- That being the case, I would expect test2 to be True, as any documentation I could find tells me if the two components should be the same type, and they should be equals (ensured by overriding Equals)

Comment: What is T? Because it's most likely that which causes it to be false. If T is a reference type then the reference type most likely is comparing reference, rather than members, in which case it will return false unless T is the exact same instance.

Comment: It would be easier to help if we could reproduce it... can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: If `T` is a class, two instances having the same *properties* aren´t equal (`Equals` returns false), unless your type `T` overrides `object.Equals` approprietaly.

Comment: Voting to close as "too board", as the code provided is not MINIMAL to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @IanRingrose The code isn't *sufficient* to reproduce the issue.  The only lines of code that seem unnecessary is that only a single value of populating the dictionary is actually needed, not several.  The rest of the code is all necessary (and again, insufficient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is required for equality:

```
t.Item2.Equals(key.Item2)
```

So it depends on `T`. If `T` is a value type this will return true if the values are equal.

If `T` is a reference type then this will only return true if both of `Item2` refer to the same instance or if `T overrides`Equals` so that different instances can be equated.

Prior to that you're checking `==` between the two instances of `T`. That's probably redundant, but it's also going to fail for the same reason. Unless you also override the `==` operator it's going to check reference types for reference equality.

I'd first remove the `==` check - just use `Equals` - and then ensure that you can expect that `Equals` to return true when you expect it to. That's either by ensuring that the `T` overrides `Equals` to give the behavior you expect, or by ensuring that both are the same instance.

Comment: In order for the code to get to the line of code `t.Equals(key)` then `t.Item2.Equals(key.Item2)` would already have had to have returned `true`, so we *know* it's true.

Comment: It seems, while I implemented a method T.Equals, which was called in my if-statement, I neglected to make it override object.Equals, which is called when comparing the Tuple type objects ^^°